# How create buttonAction functions dynamically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, programmatically-created, addtarget

In a MCQ app I create multiple `UIButton` programatically like this

```
func createNewButton(buttonName: String, xPosition: CGFloat, yPosition: CGFloat) -> UIButton {
    let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    myButton.center = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)
    myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: buttonName), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonName:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return myButton
}
```

The problem is that in order to match a function to these buttons I need to create a function. The function should therefore looks like

```
func buttonName(sender: UIButton!) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

These functions are actually going to save a string in an array, and the string to save is the name of the function itself. If we have for example `buttonName: "blackberry"`, the code is going to set an image called `"blackberry"` and add a target action named `"blackberry"` and I would like therefore a `buttonAction` function called `func blackberry(sender: UIButton)` and this function would save the string `"blackberry"` in an array of `String`.

But all of this should be done in function of the initial `buttonName: String` parameter.

Or maybe I am really not doing things the right way, and how should I do then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this instead.  Send all of your buttons to `processButton(button: UIButton)`.  When you create your buttons, set the `tag` property assigning a unique number to each button.  Then you can have an array which translates the button tag to the string.

```
var buttonNames: [String] = []
var currentIndex = 0

func createNewButton(buttonName: String, xPosition: CGFloat, yPosition: CGFloat) -> UIButton {
    let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    myButton.center = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)
    myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: buttonName), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: "processButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    myButton.tag = currentIndex++
    self.buttonNames.append(buttonName)
    return myButton
}

func processButton(button: UIButton) {
    let string = buttonNames[button.tag]
    // process string
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very beautiful solution! At first the `button.tag` was always returning `0` but I managed to set manually a tag for each button and now it works! (I didn't know about this `.tag` parameter, it is very handy).

Comment: thanks but if we had two series of buttonNames array we must define a second processButton function right? any approach to solve this?